# Resharper cntrl + f12 not working anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I ran into an issue on resharper ultimate + vs 2015.

I migrated from vs 2013 and resharper 8. Previously, cntrl f12 was "go to implementation" and f12 go to definition. Now I am getting Enter member name (search member in class) and some error checking. I tried changing the scheme, closing and restarting vs, uninstalling resharper and reinstalling but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your shortcuts here:

- Tools - Options
- Environment - Keyboard

On my pc F12 is coupled to "Edit.GotoDefinition". Ctro-F12 is coupled to "Edit.GotToDeclaration".

There is also a "Resharper_GotoDefinition/Declaration" which you could also use.